# SAS Lag and Lead functions in Teradata

Tags: sql, sas, teradata

I am wondering if there's 1:1 match to lead and lag functions in Teradata? I am doing it using Row_Number() as RowNo function, and then picking the values in the RowNo = RowNo + 1 in the join statement. Is there an easier way to perform this?

Comment: Teradata documentation for [lag and lead](https://docs.teradata.com/reader/756LNiPSFdY~4JcCCcR5Cw/GjCT6l7trjkIEjt~7Dhx4w)

Comment: Teradata 16.10+ supports LAG/LEAD, before `LAG(col) OVER (ORDER BY col2)` is similar to `MAX(col) OVER (ORDER BY col2 ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)`, `LEAD` translates to `FOLLOWING`

Comment: Teradata supports `lag()` and `lead()`.  I am not aware that SAS proc SQL does, unless passing through to another database.

Comment: Thanks guys. I will try out this method but the documentation looks quite relevant to my need. I just never saw anyone working with these functions around my workplace.